# Successfully deployed, however web:war exlpoded. Why? (Using IntelliJIDEA)

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, intellij-idea

I am getting in the application server window the following message:

> web:war exlpoded.
>   However when hovering over it says "Artifact is deployed successfully."

What does it mean "war exploded"?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, when deploying artifacts to web container, you compile you project, archive classes and resources into war file, copy war into deploy directory in the container where it is unarchived.

Now, when developing web application with IntelliJ you have an option to deploy "exploded war", where you bypass archiving and unarchiving steps to speed up code-deploy-test loop.
There's a checkbox in web artifact dialog whether you want your project to be deployed as "exploded war" or not.

Answer (score 2):

`war` is web archive file. For the app server to run it it has to uncompress the archive and deploy it. That is called as "exploding" the war.

Comment: +1. In addition, a war (as well as a jar) is simply a zip file.